# How to send response without reading entire request?

Tags: java, tomcat7, nio, servlet-3.0

I'm  creating service based on Tomcat Servlets and NIO. On input there is big XML request(~100 MB), send through HTML POST method. I want to stream only first 8 KiB, and after that immediately send response to client.

```
public class A extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*8];
        try {
            rq.getInputStream().read(buffer);
            rs.setContentType("text/plain");
            rs.getOutputStream().write("Some Response".getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
     }
}
```

There is no problem when I'm trying to send small request (few lines in content), socket works properly.

> 2016-02-01 10:44:52 Http11NioProtocol [DEBUG] Socket:
>   [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment@74f19fed:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@c478210:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
>   local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63943]], Status
>   in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [**OPEN**]

But, if I try to send a bigger request (above 100 MB), there is no response on client side.

> 2016-02-01 10:48:42 Http11NioProtocol [DEBUG] Socket:
>   [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment@2b36c88f:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@25f12241:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
>   local=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 remote=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:64079]], Status
>   in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [**CLOSED**]
>
> 2016-02-01 10:48:42 LimitLatch [DEBUG] Counting
>   down[http-nio-8080-exec-3] **latch=1**

Tomcat don't want to open socket (State out: CLOSED), before I read entire input stream request.

Is it possible to send response into client without reading entire request? According to specification, I'm able to find interesting me informations on very first 8 KiB of the request.

Comment: Your code just reads the first 8KiB

Comment: Yup, you are right, my fault :)

Answer (score 0):

your code is only read a part of request,

you can use this method to convert Stream To String

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException{
        int i = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (i != -1) {            
            i = is.read(buff);
            if(i != -1){
            sb.append(new String(buff,0,i));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

so, in your code it will be

```
public class A extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) {

        try {
            String response = convertStreamToString(rq.getInputStream());   
            rs.getOutputStream().write(response.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
     }
     private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException{
        int i = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (i != -1) {            
            i = is.read(buff);
            if(i != -1){
                sb.append(new String(buff,0,i));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

or you can use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to convert your Stream to String directly

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {            
        sb.append(scanner.next());
    }
```

so, in your code it should be

```
public class A extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest rq, HttpServletResponse rs) {

        try {
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(rq.getInputStream());
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             while (scanner.hasNext()) {            
                 sb.append(scanner.next());
             }
            rs.getOutputStream().write(sb.toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
     }

}
```

this code

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*8];
rq.getInputStream().read(buffer);
```

only read the 1024 bytes requests and stored it to buffer array (1024 bytes), method `read` will return how many bytes was read, because not at all 1024's byte will be read, if request only send 200 bytes, 824 bytes will be useless. so , if request send only 200 bytes

```
int x = rq.getInputStream().read(buffer);
```

this x , will be 200, 
so to read fully, you need to make loop

```
// integer to read
int bytesRead = 0;
// loop until bytesRead is -1 (end of request), -1 means there are no bytes to read, so it will read until there are no bytes to read
while(bytesRead != -1){
    bytesRead = rq.getInputStream().read(buffer);
    if(bytesRead != -1){
    // process the bytes here , but only process bytes from 0 to bytesRead
     }
}
```